# Why my code does't execute this statement : int(n)?

Tags: python-3.x

This code is to convert decimals to binary.
What I'm trying to do is to chop off the decimal part after diving by 2.

```
binary = []
n = 25

while n != 0:
    binary.append(n % 2)
    n = n / 2
    int(n) #this part

    print(binary)
    print(n)
    choose = input("continue?[Y/N]")
    if choose == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        break

print(list(reversed(binary)))
```

Comment: What do you hope to achieve with `int(n)` without assigning it to anything? Note that you could probably do `n = n // 2` to the same effect.

Comment: What do you expect `int(n)` to do? `int` is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) that _"Return an integer object constructed from a number or string x, or return 0 if no arguments are given..."_ - you aren't using the return of your `int(n)` function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
binary = []
n = 25

while n != 0:
    binary.append(n % 2)
    n = n / 2
    n = int(n) #assign result to n 

    print(binary)
    print(n)
    choose = input("continue?[Y/N]")
    if choose == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        break

print(list(reversed(binary)))
```